# C# XML parsing: how to differentiate between self-closing tag and other tags?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I'm using the "XmlTextReader" object in ASP.NET C# to read an xml file.
In my code I really need to differentiate between self-ending tags like

```
<img src="something" />
```

and ones that has elements inside and need ending tags like:

```
<div class="anything">
    <img src="something" />
</div>
```

I've tried the HasValue method but it didn't work out well for me. Is there any other way to detect that BEFORE actuallcy reading through the element?

I can use the ReadElementContentAsString() method, but I don't really wanna do that. I need to know whether there's something inside before going inside. or at least be able to go back.

**UPDATE**
This is how I'm reading my code

```
        reader.MoveToAttribute("id"); //I know all attributes
    if (reader.ReadAttributeValue())
        this.idField = reader.Value;


    reader.MoveToElement();
    bool goOn = true;
    while (goOn)
    {
        reader.Read();
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                switch (reader.Name)
                {

                    case "div":
                        DivType newDivTypeItem = new DivType(reader);
                        this.itemsField.Add(newDivTypeItem);
                        this.itemsElementNameField.Add(ItemsChoiceType17.div);
                        break;
                    other cases...
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                this.textField.Add(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                goOn = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you definitely need to use `XmlTextReader` at all? It makes sense if your XML is huge, but otherwise I'd use LINQ to XML...

Comment: Actually I didn't know about LINQ to XML when I first needed to parse the XML. However I've went with XmlTextReader according to my search and it worked really well so far. The posted problem is my only problem right now. LINQ to XML would've been better I guess. But redoing the code would be a lot harder. I'd appreciate solving this with XmlTextReader. PS: I'll update my question

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead. This is a perfect example of why not to learn by using the Internet. Your search has found obsolete information.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'll make changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the [IsElementEmpty property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.isemptyelement.aspx) what you want? How exactly are you reading your document such that this is coming up?

Comment: Hello, I've added the loop I'm using to read. I've made a class for each possible element and each class constructor has an XmlTextReader object as a parameter. The result is a recursive reading of elements. the Code is pretty robust but the missing closing tags of some elements are making problems for me. I just need to detect them

Comment: Is that property not what you want then?

Comment: Yes it seems that's what I'm looking for! I'm amazed how I've missed it. I tried to fiend .is... properties couldn't find it. How stupid of me. sorry and thank you.

Comment: +1 for the answer, i just need add an tip: When calling IsEmptyElement after calling to read attributes, will return false even if the tag is self-closing. Consider calling IsEmptyElement as sooner before you call another methods to get attributes, etc.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kwRZPKO.png